# Performing an indirect sort in numpy, preserving same indices for identical elements

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Let's assume I have an array like this:

```
a = np.array([5, 2, 13, 13, 222])
```

I want to convert it to an array like this:

```
b = np.array([1, 0, 2, 2, 3])
```

I've tried np.argsort, but returns

```
np.argsort(np.array([5, 2, 13, 13, 222])) # = array([1, 0, 2, 3, 4])
```

which doesn't do exactly what I need it to do (it still assigns different indexes to identical elements.

So far I've written this little function to do what I want:

```
def indexate_array(v):
    v_unique = np.unique(v)
    result = shape_like(v)
    dic = {value: result for value, result in zip(v_unique, np.argsort(v_unique))}
    for i, val in enumerate(v):
        result[i] = dic[val]
    return result
```

Is there an elegant way to perform the operation I want using numpy/scipy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what the `return_inverse` parameter to [`numpy.unique`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) does:

```
In [5]: np.unique(a, return_inverse=True)
Out[5]: (array([  2,   5,  13, 222]), array([1, 0, 2, 2, 3]))
```

Answer (score 0):

And in case you needed something similar but without the `numpy` library

```
a = [5, 2, 13, 13, 222]
b = [1, 0, 2, 2, 3]
min_ranks = {}
for rank,key in enumerate(sorted(a)):
    min_ranks[key] = min(rank, min_ranks[key]) if key in min_ranks else rank

c = [ min_ranks[k] for k in a]
print(c)
```